# Tearadata add large minutes to timestamp results in overflow

Tags: date, integer, overflow, teradata

For a recordset I have an Integer field DTM which is the number of minutes from a base date. To get a trip date from a base date + the minutes increment, my first instinct was to write this in Tearadata Studio:

```
timestamp '1984-01-01 00:00:00' AS "BASEDATE",
BASEDATE + CAST(DTM AS INTERVAL MINUTE) AS TripDate
```

Looking at the spec for INTERVAL MINUTE type it holds a SMALLINT which is easily overflowed by my column DTM. An example value for DTM is 24282064.

So my question is how can I get the calculated field TripDate without loosing accuracy? Should I convert it to hours? or days? Would that keep my original accuracy?

I tried:

```
DTM/60 AS DTH,
```

But seems to be outputting only integers and i would theorize that some would be floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teradata's limitation to four significant digits for intervals is quite stupid (there have been enhancement requests for almost 20 years now), thus you always need some workaround.

If the interval is known to be less than 27 years:

```
BASEDATE + (DTM * INTERVAL '0000 00:01' DAY TO MINUTE)
```

But in most cases it's larger and then you have to do two steps:

```
Cast(DATE '1984-01-01' + (dtm / 1440) AS TIMESTAMP(0)) -- add days first
+ Cast(dtm MOD 1440 AS INTERVAL MINUTE)                -- add the remaining minutes
```

Comment: Ok I tried this and it works but I believe the 3600 should be 1440 shouldn't it? 24 hours per day * 60 minutes per hour = 1440. So Cast(DATE '1984-01-01' + (dtm / 1440) AS TIMESTAMP(0)) -- add days first + Cast(dtm MOD 1440AS INTERVAL MINUTE)                -- add the remaining minutes